# Accessing Objects Made in Array from Different Class

Tags: java, arrays

i am having trouble trying to figure out how to access objects that were made in an array in another class from Main. Psuedo for what im trying to do.

- In Main CLass Prompt user for number of Tables In the Restaurant
- take number n, create array of n Table objects in Restaurant Class
- Access each tableobject created and be able to add values to it via constructor all from main

Hopefully the code can Explain Better.

My Main Class

```
Restaurant RestaurantObject = new Restaurant(); 
Table TableObject = new Table();

System.out.println("Max Tables In Restaurant? (Interger)");//Set Max Tables
Scanner smax_tables = new Scanner(System.in);
int max_tables = smax_tables.nextInt();
RestaurantObject.create_table_array(TableObject, max_tables);
```

My Restaurant Class

```
private Table[] TableList; //and other random variables
//other methods

public void create_table_array(Table table,int number) {
        Table[] TableList = new Table[number];
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            TableList[i] = table;
        }
public Restaurant() {

}
```

My Table CLass

```
 int max_amount;

    public int getMax() {
        return max_amount
   }

    Table(int number) {
        this.max_amount = number;
    }
```

And my desired action

- run program and enter 5 for max tables
- 5 tables created in restaurant
- `RestaurantObject.Table1(10) //set max to 10 in table object`
- `System.out.printf("max amount for table1 is %d",Restaurant.Table1.getMax()`

Now that im re-looking at it. Would i have to prompt the user for the table to edit, get and return that table object in the array? Any help would be great,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get your question right, the you want to access the array created here :

```
public void create_table_array(Table table,int number) {
    Table[] tableList = new Table[number];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++) 
            tableList[i] = table;
}
```

What you can do is change the method from `void` to `Table[]` and return the created array. Like this:

```
public Table[] create_table_array(Table table,int number) {
    Table[] tableList = new Table[number];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++) 
            tableList[i] = table;

    return tableList;
}
```

Now in your main program, you can call the method like this:

```
Table[] tables = RestaurantObject.create_table_array(TableObject, max_tables);
```

Now you can access all tables by their indices. For example

```
for(int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
    //do something to tables[i]
```

Also, you should stick with JAVA naming conventions and use camelCase for variable names. For example: `TableList`==>`tableList` etc...